# Spark unsplittable/splittable input files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a parquet file which I believe is "unsplittable", and when I use Spark to read this file, the spark UI looks like this
[image]

So basically all data was loaded into a single partition, causing OOM error.

I used more resources to read this file, then write out to disk using Spark

```
df = spark.read.load(inputFile)
df.repartition(1).write.format("parquet").mode("append").save(outputFile)
```

Then I read this "outputFile" into Spark again, and looks like the file is now "splittable", and Spark UI looks like this[image]

data is now evenly distributed / read into Spark in parallel.

I tried to reproduce a "splittable" parquet file by using **pandas/pyarrow/fastparquet**, with **snappy/gzip/none** compression algorithms, but none of them seems to be "splittable", when I read it into Spark, Spark UI looks exactly like the first picture.

My question is, how can I produce a "splittable" parquet file(besides using Spark), so that when Spark reads it, reads it in parallel (like in second picture)?

Comment: Have you tried increasing `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` and `spark.default.parallelism`? Here you can find these parameters explained: https://dzone.com/articles/apache-spark-performance-tuning-degree-of-parallel

Comment: Yes, in my case I need to load 20 of ~7GiB files, I tried to set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to 2000 and `spark.default.parallelism` to 500/1000. The UI looked like the first picture, i.e. 20 partitions each load entire 7GiB data, leaving the rest partitions almost empty (a few hundred KiB).

Comment: But you load from file, right? Can you check, whether you don't have the `inputFile` in form of directory with one huge file, and handful of smaller ones?

Comment: Yes, the `inputFile` is a 7GiB parquet file, like `path/to/directory/foobar.pqt`, it is not a directory of files. Do you suggest that I put it in a directory and read the directory, instead of reading the file directly? i.e. `spark.read.load(path/to/directory)`

Comment: Well, in general you cannot split reading the single file into multiple threads (executors). In general I would tackle how this file is created, and not how it's read. So eg. Assuming I have 7GB dataframe, while writing I would do something like: `df.repartition(100).write.parquet(dir)` which would create 100 files in directory `dir` , around 70MB each. Which is subject to block size, but it's a safe call for usable file size. 7GB is unusable in pyspark sense - because you have to load the whole file at once.

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzSkibinski. I totally agree with your suggestion. This 7GiB large file was created by our upstream team using pandas `to_parquet` method with `snappy` compression. I'm trying to investigate if there exists a way to create a single parquet file that is "splittable", besides using Spark (like the `outputFile` I described in the question because the upstream team does not use Spark). But if this is not achievable by any means, then I'll have to ask them to create multiple smaller files instead of one large file.

Comment: What is your `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` - The maximum number of bytes to pack into a single partition when reading files (default 128MB) ? This has a very strong influence on the number of spark partitions you end up with.
For tuning, I go straight to the task summary UI, compare the total tasks, plus median and max values of the task metrics.

Comment: Then in `pandas` you can do: `df["part"] = np.arange(len(df))//100` and then, while saving: `df.to_parquet(partition_cols=["part"], path=<sir>)` this way you wil obtain 100 files, each around 70 MB, instead of a single 7GB file. Which then will be super easy to cope for spark.